# jquery click function not triggered

Tags: jquery, html

I have a jquery which needs to fire when on click event. When I try it on site like w3schoools try jquery, it fires. But in my application, it fails to fire. Below is my script.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".vouch").click(function(){
            alert("000");
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <li class="vouch">
        <a href=""><span>tooo</span></a>
    </li>
```

When i change the class `.vouch` to a different class, it fires. seems like there is something blocking the working of the code. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: include jquery reference in your code it will work for sure

Comment: Any error messages in the browser console?

Comment: You have some invalid markup there. `li` should be nested within `ul` or `ol`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [your code](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/ya8ak/), the `click` event is being attached to the `.vouch` element at the time of `document.ready`, but then is "stuck" to that element. Even if you change the class, the event handler remains bound to the `li` element itself.

To do what you want, use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). This *delegates* the `click` event to the `document` instead, but checks if the clicked element has the `vouch` class at the time of the click before executing the code.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $(document).on('click', '.vouch', function () {
         alert("000");
     });
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/H88PU/

Comment: Now i understand what "stuck" means.. the classes are dynamically changed by other javascript. so this could be a problem which i never thought of. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your `<head>`

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and it should work

Answer (score 0):

You have to include jQuery in your `head`: it's an external library.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

**[Your code works fine.](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/S6ehF/)**

Whenever something doesn't work in JS, it's a good idea to check your browser console for errors.

In this case, you would have seen something like `$ is not defined`, which usually means that you didn't include jQuery or you're trying to execute your JS before jQuery loads.